# External Bootable C:\ Drive for Windows

Tags: hard-disk

I need to be able to test software on different Windows OS and I'm not able to use Virtual Machines. Currently, I clone drives and plug them into a SATA cable inside the PC case. The cloned drives have the Windows OS installed and I can boot to the drive, install the test s/w, test and then re-clone the drives. Now, I would like to be able to do this without having to open the PC case. Can I use a SATA port on the back and a hard drive docking station to boot to Windows? Would an external hard drive with SATA be more appropriate?

Comment: Take a simple 2.5" SSD, use an external SATA III to USB 3 single drive enclosure, and within bios select that device to boot from.

Comment: Also, there are enclosure with eSATA connections.  There are a plethora of options, most of which only require browsing newegg or other sites.  Though I am not quite sure how this is exactly technical support as you are asking for information on what hardware to use to fulfill a specific purpose.

Comment: I vote to reopen based upon ArtofCode's own [answer](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/426/lets-explain-what-technical-support-means-and-how-to-properly-fix-the-questio) to a what is a tech support question thread.   Case Study #2 to be exact.